# MQ light not responding to SSL requests after enabling SSL

Tags: ibm-mq

I installed the MQ Light server on Windows 7 and followed the steps at https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/docs/mq-light-api/tutorials/security-tutorial/ to enable SSL using a self signed certificate generated by OpenSSL 1.1.0g.

At that point, once I started the MQ light server, my browser timed out trying to do the TLS handshake to the server and any attempt to connect to the server immediately using the Java MQ libraries aborted because the server closed the connection.

I couldn't figure out where the MQ server logs are to check them.  Disabling SSL results in the connection working again.

I'm using Oracle Java 8u161 (64-bit).

Any idea what's going on here and how to get SSL working?

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(5671)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[Remote host closed connection during handshake],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:5671 (localhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]],3=localhost(5671),5=RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2282)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1294)
at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:376)
at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:560)
at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.MQCONNX_j(MQSESSION.java:916)
at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:235)
... 16 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[Remote host closed connection during handshake],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:5671 (localhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1329)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:863)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:409)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:305)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1730)
... 21 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$6.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1298)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$6.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1290)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1290)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
... 33 more
```

Comment: I managed to connect with my application, but MQ light returns a 2400 error code indicating the ciphersuite isn't supported.  I still can't find logs for MQ light or connect with a browser, so I have no idea what ciphersuite it thinks is connecting.  I notice MQ light using IBM Java and my application is using Oracle Java so there may be a mismatch in the Ciphersuite names.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show more information how how your client is configured.  What Cipher Suite are you using?